# Delete all rows older than 30 days with single query once in a month MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to delete rows older than 30 days automaticly but i can't findout how

I dont need query like

```
"delete from table where date"
```

I heard that there is mysql stored procedures but can't find how to solve my task using that

1 Is there any other way to solve task?

2 Could you share link to tutorial where explainig mysql stored procedures deleting rows like i want to do?

I am asking because of i found some results on google and here on stackoverflow but nothing helped.

Comment: So, what's the bit you're stuck with? The "older than 30 days" part or the "once a month" part? You're aware that you can compare dates with < right? (`WHERE someDate < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAYS)`)

Comment: @Caius Jard I need to know how to store query that deleting rows older than 30 days without user iteration automaticly with mysql stored procedures and I need to know how and where to save query

Comment: See mysql events - etails are in the answers to the duplicate question.